# Фильтрация ссылок и их замена

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, мне не обходимо сделать фильтр по разделам на своём сайте. К примеру у меня есть меню с выпадающими списками: Главная ( выпадающий список: Форум, контакты ), Портфолио ( выпадающий список: Все работы, в работе ).

Можно ли как то сделать, чтоб при переходе по этим ссылкам они сохранялись в переменных и затем из этих значений можно построить ссылку.

Пример: rus-buket.ru

В фильтре мы выбираем: кому, цена, по случаю, при переходах ссылка заменяется и значения сохраняются. Как такое реализовать?